# how to use memcpy to initialize a char pointer in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memcpy

this is how I define struct.

```
struct urlFormat
{
      int port;
      char *host;
      char *path;
      int cat;
      char *status;
};
```

this is how I initialize strcut and allocate the space for the pointer.

```
struct urlFormat *res;
res = malloc(sizeof(struct urlFormat));
```

when I used memcpy() function, it reported segmentation fault.

```
char *ptr1 = (char *)url;
  int len = strlen(ptr1);
  memcpy(res->host, ptr1, len);
```

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You don't allocate any memory for `host` to point to; you have only allocated memory for the `struct`.

Comment: so I just need to res->host = malloc(sizeof(char*)) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`res->host` is just a pointer (that is not pointing to anything yet).

Until `res->host` is pointing to some valid memory you can't `memcpy` to it.

You can either `malloc` some memory `res->host = malloc(len + 1);`(+1 for the 0 terminator and `sizeof(char)` is always 1 so omit it) or in this case just use `res->host = strdup(ptr1);`

Comment: Comment now deleted but OP asked how to copy part of a string: You need to allocate space for as much as you want to copy and then copy that amount. `strncpy` would do it or you could use `strdup` and just put a 0 in the string after the last character that you want. This wastes a bit of memory but is completely legal. It all depends on what you really want to do.